# How to run python script continuously on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I have a python script that I want to run continuously. I have tried using the procfile but nothing has worked.

```
worker: python file.py
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you... show us `file.py`? Is this file even a process that does not exit?

Comment: I was using    file.py as an example. But when I check the logs, it always crashes.

Answer (score 0):

it is very bad practice to run a python scripts continuously on heroku server. There is an add-on on heroku named, scheduler. Try this app and make a schedule to run your scripts after some time in a day or month. what ever you want.